# Javascript deleting cookies with an HTML table

Tags: javascript, html, cookies

I was trying to make a code that when you introduce a table row (clicking on a button) it use the first cell from the row as name of a cookie. That's fine, at least atm.

My problem is that when i try to delete a row from that table I want to delete the cookie that is associated with that, not that hard, but i'm not really sure what am i doing wrong.

Thanks!

http://jsfiddle.net/roucher/d9h6onvr/

```
    function borrarTR() {
    document.getElementById("tablaPaseadores").deleteRow(0);
    contador--;
    var x = document.getElementById("tablaPaseadores").rows.length;
    var celda = "celda" + x + "1";
    alert(celda);
    var cname = document.getElementById(celda).innerHTML;
    alert(cname + "1");
    deleteCookie(cname);
```

It dosent alert that last alert: "(cname + "1")" So I guess the problem is in celda, but celda returns the right value.

EDIT: Solved.

I had 2 errors: first and main one, if i try to get the id of something that has been already deleted, it will obviously return null.
And second, I should have realised also that the lenght in from [1-i] and I am working from [0-i-1] so i had to do this to solve both:

```
function borrarTR() {
    var x = (document.getElementById("tablaPaseadores").rows.length)-1;
    var celda = "celda" + x + "1";
    var cname = document.getElementById(celda).innerHTML;
    document.getElementById("tablaPaseadores").deleteRow(0);
    contador--;
    deleteCookie(cname);
}
```

Comment: Checked your console ? Want a tip ? Write `debugger` in the first line of your function, then press F12 before run your code.

Comment: @DontVoteMeDown "TypeError: document.getElementById(...) is null" but don't know why, i've used it previously and worked perfectly

Comment: Probably `celda` contains an `id` which doesn't exists in your current document(at least at the time it is used).

Comment: celda is created with cookie data and the id is given as it is created, im testing how to delete an existing row, i don't know if i am explaning properly @DontVoteMeDown

Comment: You actually did explain, but I don't know what is your `deleteCookie()`. If its native, I don't know it.

Comment: I've realised about how dumb can I be, so just solved it, sorry for wasting your time @DontVoteMeDown EDIT: my deleteCookie wasn't a problem, and i knew since it didnt reach the alert previous to that. If you are curious, you have the fiddle link, you can enter and test it ;)